# How to lower the power consumption of this ESP32 during delay(500)?

Tags: power, esp32, battery, sleep

The following code works. It does the following:

- wake up when pin `GPIO0` is connected to `GND`  (the pulse duration is 400 milliseconds)
- once every 10 wakings, I send the current index to a server with a HTTP request over WiFi
- then go to deep sleep

Since `GPIO0` is connected to `GND` during 400 milliseconds, it can reboot **multiple times** during these 400 milliseconds, which I don't want. So I added `delay(500);` at the end of the code.

Problem: this `delay(500);` is probably a waste of power, since the ESP32 is battery powered.

**Question: by what could I replace this `delay(500)` to avoid that the ESP32 reboots multiple times while pin 0 is connected to `GND` during 400 milliseconds, with the least power consumption possible?**

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include "HTTPClient.h"
#include "esp_sleep.h"
byte WIFI_BSSID[] =         {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0x00};
String URL =                "http://example.com/submit?bootcount=";
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootcount = 0;
HTTPClient http;
void setup() {
    bootcount++;  
    pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
    esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_0, 0);
    if (bootcount % 10 == 0) {
        WiFi.begin("MySSID", "password", 0, WIFI_BSSID);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            delay(20); 
        }
        URL += bootcount;
        http.begin(URL.c_str());
        http.GET();
        http.end();
    }
    delay(500);
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
void loop() {
}
```

Comment: `it happens during 400 milliseconds` ... what does this mean? ... does the pin interrupt happen every 400 ms?

Comment: @jsotola It's like a switch: usually `pin 0` is not connected to `GND`. Then when a pulse happens, during 400 ms `pin 0` is connected to `GND`, it's the pulse duration.

Comment: so, you want the ESP32 to wake only on the transition of GPIO0 ... perhaps a simple circuit could be used to modify the input pulse ... maybe the ULP processor could be used

Comment: @jsotola Yes, since the pulse lasts 400ms, if I don't add the `delay(500)`, multiple "wake_up+increment_bootcount+deep_sleep" sequences can happen during one signe pulse. I want to wake up only on the transition. Do you think there is a purely software way (without additional hardware components), other than my `delay(500)` solution? And possibly that doesn't require to stay fully powered during the 500ms?

Comment: If the chip cannot be waked by the transition, you might consider to use a timer. Start it when the delay shall start, disable the pin interrupt, and go to sleep. Let the timer overflow/interrupt wake up the chip again, stop the timer, enable the pin interrupt, and go to sleep. Please be aware that a running timer might not allow a deep sleep.

Comment: Instead of driving the Pin 0 directly, add a small capacity (0.1uF) in serial between the driver and the Pin0, so that it generate a short pulse during the transition but not during the entire holding down period.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks I will try this. Also, isn't there a 100% code solution without hardware? It fully works with `delay(500)`, the only problem is that it probably consumes 100 mA or 200 mA during these 500 milliseconds. Is there a `deep_sleep_delay(500)` or something similar that would consume max 1 mA ?

Comment: As I suggested, a timer needs no _additional_ hardware, your microcontroller certainly has such timers. In that sense this is a "100% code" solution, just try it. -- Since you say that there is no "edge-triggered" wake-up but only a "level-triggered" wake-up, `delay(500)` is the only "100% code" solution, as it simply runs an empty loop. Anything else needs _something more_ to measure the time or change the trigger.

Comment: @thebusybee oh ok thank I initially didn't understand! Would you have a short code example to demonstrate this part (timer), as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have an ESP32 here, not to mention a compiler. Please try this yourself, this is the way you will learn. SE/Arduino is not a code writing service. ;-)

Comment: I know ;) @thebusybee btw I already wrote the code (in my question). But by experience, often the devil is in the details, so sometimes some code can be useful for an answer :)